# Crashing issue. Suspect Nvidia drivers

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg

After quite some kerfuffle I managed to get to activate the proprietary nvidia drivers. Chose

```
xorg:nvidia_current
```

My attempts seemed successful but now Ubuntu freezes after a minute or two and it wont enter failsafe graphical mode. The following is displayed when attempting it:

```
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.11 (for technical support please see www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current  version of pixman 0.24.4
    before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org 
    to make sure that you have the latest version
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting, 
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational, 
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implimented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/var/log/xorg.failsafe.log", Time Sat Feb 9 11:37:46 2013
(++) Using config file: "/etc/x11/xorg.conf.failsafe"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/x11/xorg.conf.d
vesa: Ignoring devide with a bound kernel driver

Fatal server error:
No screens found

Please consult the X.org Foundation support
      at http://wiki.x.org

 for help.
Please also check "/var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log" for additional information

ddxSigGiveUo: Closing log
Server terminated with error (1) Closing log file.
```

Now I've had a look on the x.Org website but can't see an explanation of the error, or how to fix it.

With Ubuntu crashing as quickly as it does I can't open the log files in time to see the contents and I'm still not sufficiently conversant with the text based file system to find and open the logs and config files to open them to see what they say.

Do I need to uninstall the nvidia_drivers and then re-install a different set? 
How can I do that?
If it helps the graphics chipset on my laptop is a nVidia 6100 GO so hardly new hardware.
Or could it be the fiddling I've been trying with broadcom drivers?

Whatever it is I've done I've made ubuntu pretty much un-usable so would really love help on this one.

What other information might you need to assist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had issues with my NVIDIA card (GTX 650 ti). Try the following:

- Go to your console and press Ctrl+Alt+F1
- Uninstall the drivers

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

- Install packages for your kernel

`sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-source linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic` (That's my kernel, you get to know yours by typing `uname -r`in a terminal

- A great PPA is provided by [those guys](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates). Those are more stable and reliable than in the official repos. Add them and do an update by using these commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates&&sudo apt-get update`

- Install drivers

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

- Check if your driver is installed correctly

`lsmod | grep nvidia`

- If not, then you have to manually activate it:

`sudo depmod -a`

- Load it

`sudo modprobe nvidia_current`

- Restart

Hopefully it works for you!

Comment: I shall give that a go - it's difficult as I have to currently reboot an awful lot - into windows to get access to the interwebs. I've been taking photographs of answers to problems.

Comment: @Myranda I know that sucks, just give it a try and let's see

Comment: Thank you! I now have all my drivers installed, and it looks stable. You're awesome!

Comment: @Myranda Great, I am happy I could help you!